# How can I configure CMake to synchronize source code to a remote host

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm new to CMake and am working towards the goal of having a codebase that I can execute both on my local windows machine and on a remote linux server.  I find myself with a chicken-vs-egg problem.  I would like to use CMake to stage my source code on the remote machine; but the CMake script is unable to find these files on the remote machine and thus errors out prior to doing a copy.

Local windows development is working as expected.  Source code is on my local file system, and this simplified CMakeLists.txt at the root of my project is able to get the job done.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MySampleApp VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(MySampleApp main.cpp program_options.h program_options.cpp )
```

However, when I change CMake target to the remote linux server, I get the following error:

`cannot find source file: main.cpp`

At this stage, I think it makes sense for this to error out, because the file *hasn't actually been transferred yet*.  But this begs the question "how do I get it there?"

Below is a listing of the settings for the linux build.  I would expect that `remoteCopySources` would ensure that things are synced from local vs remote.

```json
"name": "Linux-GCC-Debug",
"generator": "Ninja",
"configurationType": "Debug",
"cmakeExecutable": "cmake",
"remoteCopySourcesExclusionList": [ ".vs", ".git", "out" ],
"cmakeCommandArgs": "",
"buildCommandArgs": "",
"ctestCommandArgs": "",
"inheritEnvironments": [ "linux_x64" ],
"remoteMachineName": "${defaultRemoteMachineName}",
"remoteCMakeListsRoot": "/path/to/server/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/src",
"remoteBuildRoot": "/path/to/server/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/out/build/${name}",
"remoteInstallRoot": "/path/to/server/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/out/install/${name}",
"remoteCopySources": true,
"rsyncCommandArgs": "-t --delete",
"remoteCopyBuildOutput": false,
"remoteCopySourcesMethod": "rsync",
"variables": []
```

How can I correctly define my file paths, such that they describe where the file *will* be staged once the script is completed and the sync occurs?  Am I overlooking a better approach to ensuring my source code is in sync for both systems?

Comment: CMake is a build manager. You should use another tool to CD your code to a different platform.

Comment: Modern IDEs like VSS or CLion comes with remote toolchain features that helps you run the project on a different environment without switching workspaces. I’d advise trying that out instead.

Comment: Basically you want to use CMake for something it was not designed for. I recommend looking at something that trickers your build manager (CMake) and then deploys the code on the remote node.

Comment: Fair points @haleyk & Lars Nielsen.  

Perhaps I had incorrect expectations set by how visual studio treats remote c++ linux development when the code is configured using .sln and .proj files.  I got that approach working prior to looking into the CMake alternative.  With the .sln approach source code sync to the remote host works out of the box.

I've transitioned to manually syncing code and that is working for now.  Thank you for the comments.

Comment: I do think that the existence of fields like "remoteCopySources" "remoteCopySourcesExclusionList" and "copySourcesOptions" in cmakesettings.json speaks to the fact that this file copying behavior is in scope for CMake, at least in some fashion.  Why would these settings exist otherwise?

I'll continue to try and will update this question if I find an approach that works.

Comment: @JoshJones CMakeSettings.json is VSS specific feature to integrate with CMake. It has nothing to do with CMake itself.

Comment: That is helpful context to have.  Thank you for helping me narrow down the VSS specific behavior vs the CMake behavior; my expectations were definitely misaligned at first.